# Samsung Galaxy Nexus not showing in ADT

Tags: android, windows-8

I'm having a major problem trying to get this Galaxy Nexus showing up in ADT.

I tried installing all the drivers from Samsung, but no luck.

My driver details for the device shows me using the Microsoft Driver from 2006. Clearly this is not correct. So I tried uninstalling with no luck. I also tried to update driver and point to at one of the Crazy names in the SAMSUNG/USB Driver folder, however Windows thinks it's smarter than me and always says "it has determined the driver software for my device is up to date" and then lists the device as MTP USB Device.

The phone appears as

Portable Devices
Galaxy Nexus

in device manager.

I've tried switching the phone in both MTP and PTP mode with no luck.

Update: After mashing on disable and uninstall for a while I finally got the device to use the "SAMSUNG Electronics Co., Ltd" while in MTP mode. However it still does not appear under adb devices and when I switch to PTP mode it goes back to using the old Microsoft Drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. So I guess my phone updated itself to 4.2 and "Developer Options" was hidden by default. This also made my phone turn off USB debugging.

Anyways.... Turn it on http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html
and make sure the recent update didn't turn off that option.